Matplotlib - Latex Premable Package not loading
I want to use LaTeX in the x-label of a plot. I need the label to be \varepsilon with a subscript that is a smaller version of the \parallel symbol. This is what I have tried but it does not work, I get ParseSyntaxException: Unknown symbol: \scalebox, found '\'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

rc('font',**{'family':'STIXGeneral'})
rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{graphicx}')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel(r"$\mathregular{\varepsilon_{\scalebox{0.8}{\parallel}}}$")
plt.show()

